# Purpose of setting the loop count

Tags: automation, jmeter, load-testing

What is the purpose of setting the loop count? Is it just depend on how many times i want to run the test? Or it has other purpose of test with different loop count? Will it affect the final test result?

"If you give loop count as 2 then every request two times to the server"

I found this online, but i don't understand what it means.

Based on my understanding, the loop count set to 2 because of i want to repeat the test twice only. After the first test end, then the threads in first round test in dead before the second test starts. Then the new thread group will send the request to the server. Why "every request two times to the server"?

Answer (score 0):

The loop count means each thread of your thread group will run the steps inside the loop twice if iteration is set to 2

The thread will start based on delay and rampup and not related to this setting

Answer (score 0):

If your server has concurrent users limit, for example 100, and you want to execute more, as 600, you can set loop count as 6 and execute 600 requests with given server limits

Comment: "...execute 600 requests with given server limits..."
but based on my understanding, 100 request will dead when run another loop? in each loop, 100 requests will send to server, repeat for 6 times. 
use back ur example, my server has concurrent users limit (100),
Scenario 1 (thread: 600, loop count:1)
Scenario 2 (thread: 100, loop count:6)
What is the different?

Comment: @萌萌哒蚂蚁 scenario 1 - server will failed to server some of the requests, because it can server only up to 100 at a time

Answer (score 0):

It's the number of times for each JMeter thread (virtual user) to execute [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) inside the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

Each JMeter thread executes Samplers upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)) so if there are no more Samplers to execute the thread will shut down. And it might be the case you won't be able to achieve the desired concurrency because some threads have already finished execution and some haven't been yet started like it's described in the [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) so you might want to increase the number of iterations or even set it to "Infinite" and control the test duration using "Duration" section of the Thread Group or [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)